# What are we doing here and what are Hermenutics?

Tags: discussion

From Milton S. Terrys Biblical hermenutics

Hermenutics is the science of interpretation. The word is usually applied to the ***explanation of written documents***, and may therefore be more specifically designed as the science of interpretation of an authors language. This science assumes that there are divers modes of thought and ambiguities of expression among men, and, accordingly, it aims to remove the supposable differences between a writer and his readers, so that the meaning of the one may be truly and accurately apprehended by the others.

It is common to distinguish between***general*** and ***special*** Hermenutics. General hermenutics is devoted to the general principles which are applicable to the interpretation of all languages and writing. It may  appropriately take cognizance of the logical operations of the Human mind, and the philosophy of human speech. ***Special*** hermenutics is devoted rather to the explanation of particular books and classes of writings. Thus, historical, poetical, philosophical and prophetical writings differ from each other in numerous particulars, and each class requires for its proper exposition of the application of principles and methods adapted to its own peculiar character and style. ***Special*** hermenutics, according to Cellerier, ***is a science practical and almost empirical***, and searches after rules and solutions; wile ***General*** Hermenutics is methodical and Philosophical, and searches for principles and methods.

People who join this site really need a clear understanding of what hermenutics are. Of course you have a page with the rules, but am not sure if it is clear or concise enough for an average John like me. After reading this Im up to 99% on understanding what Hermenutics are. Wether the understanding will be conveyed in my future Q&A I doubt sincerely never the less the house is not finished yet.!

Definitely the wrong place to post this but sometimes rules are for breaking.

Comment: [I wrote a tome about this.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/671/423) You may enjoy reading it.

Comment: @Dan Thanks Dan..will read it properly after. Yeah its a long one..Looking forward.!

Comment: Thats as close as we are going to get. Mystery surrounds Gods will and purpose...as the prophet said, "SURELY YOU ARE A GOD WHO HIDES HIMSELF OH  GOD OF ISRAEL SAVIOR". That was a great read and very enlightening. It answered some difficult questions..one in-particular regarding the way the inspired authors wrote scripture.! Ive been battling with this issue for a while...those who claim one version is inspired as for the KJV, are actually claiming that the translators of the same were inspired. This cannot be the case..! The Holy Spirit, interprets the spirit of the text  to the elect.!